# Cannot use some themes within Managed WordPress of Go Daddy

Tags: themes

Some themes display blank pages instead of my home page when I activate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have set up your site to use a specific static page as the site home page and another as the blog home page. If you haven't, the default is to show posts on the site home.

Next check to see if the themes include both index.php and home.php. Typically home.php is used for the home page of the blog, and index.php for the site home page with page.php being used for internal pages. If your site requires one of these templates and it isn't there, that could be the problem. Generally if home.php isn't there, then WP falls back on index.php. If that is the case then you want to look at index.php to make sure if is using the right WordPress loop. If you compare the files between a theme that works and one that doesn't that should help you isolate this problem. Good luck.